# Filter map by its value using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I am new to Java streams and want to run the below code using streams.

```
 List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    if (stats.containsKey("roles")) {
            roles = stats.get("roles");
    } else {
            Map<String, String> roleMap = stats.containsKey("attributes") ? 
                       stats.get("attributes") : new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : roleMap.entrySet()) {
                    if (e.getValue().equals("true")) {
                            roles.add(e.getKey());
                    }
            }
    }
```

In the above code I am doing the following steps :

1. I have a `stats` hashmap in which first I am checking if the `roles` key is present, if it is present I am returning the corresponding value.
2. if the `stats` hashmap does not contain the `roles` key,  I am checking if `stats` hashmap contains key `attributes`.
3. If the `attribute` key present then its value is Hashmap and then I am traversing the hashmap and checking wherever its value is equal to "true", I am adding the corresponding key to my `roles` list.

**Input:**

```
{
    "attributes":{
        "id":false
        "name":true
    }
       
}
```

**Output:**

```
["name"]
```

Can this whole code be reduced by streams?

Comment: Feel free to add test data end expected output.

Comment: How `stats` map is defined ? It is defined like `Map<String, String>` or  `Map<String, List<String>>`? Please provide your input and expected output here.

Comment: Your loop part can be replaced with this way `roleMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e-> e.getValue().equals("true")).map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList())` other if-else part is okay I think, though have same confussion as @SudhirOjha point out.

Comment: @SudhirOjha @Eklavya @Antoniossss stats map is defined as `Map<String, Object>`. Have updated my question, with input and expected output

Comment: You need to fix your code and provide a [mre] that works.  Your code, as show, is broken and won't compile even if the stats map is provided.  As you are trying to pull different types of values from the same map. In one case you're assigning a value to a `List<String>` from stats and later trying to assign a value from the same map to `Map<String,String>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much this will help. Using streams in your use case according to me is not simplifying the solution, but if you want to use then you can do something like this in your code.

```
 Map<String,Object> stats=new HashMap<>();
       List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        stats.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(i -> {
                    if (i.getKey().contains("roles")) {
                        roles.add((String)i.getValue());
                    } else if(i.getKey().contains("attributes")){
                        Map<String, String> roleMap=  (Map<String, String>)i.getValue();
                        roleMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(j-> {
                            if (j.getValue()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                                roles.add(j.getKey());
                    });
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 stats.keySet().stream().filter(s->s.equals("roles")).findFirst().map(s->stats.get("roles")).orElseGet(()->{
        List list=  Lists.newArrayList();
        stats.get("attributes").foreach((k,v)->{
             if v;list.add(k)
         })
       return list;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values of the keys `roles` and `attributes` were of same type (`List<String>`) you could easily do something like

```
List<String> roles = stats.getOrDefault("roles",
                          stats.getOrDefault("attributes", new ArrayList<>()));
```

You could still use this approach, but since the assosiated values are of different types you need to make some casting which makes your code maybe a little bit unintuitive:

```
Map<String, Object> stats = new HashMap<>();
stats.put("roles", Arrays.asList("role1", "role2"));
stats.put("attributes", Map.of("id", "false", "name", "true"));

List<String> roles = (List<String>) stats.getOrDefault("roles",
                     ((Map<String, String>) stats.getOrDefault("attributes", new HashMap<>()))
                                        .entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .filter(i -> i.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                                        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(roles);
```